# DataTable Syntax error in the expression Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, select, datatable, dataset

I may be looking over something very simple this morning but I am receiving the following error:

> Syntax error in the expression

On this line of code:

```
Dim result() As DataRow = tmp_Table.Select("id, name, Snippet, description, lat, lng, " & _
```

When trying to query my dataTable in vb.net.

Here is my code:

```
Dim tmp_Table As DataTable = New DataTable("radiusDataFromCSV")
Dim center_lat As Double = 0
Dim center_lng As Double = 0
Dim radius As Integer = 0

Dim tmpName As String = ""
Dim tmpSnippet As String = ""
Dim tmpdescription As String = ""
Dim tmpcoordinates As String = ""
Dim tmpLat As Double = 0
Dim tmpLng As Double = 0

'Add columns.
tmp_Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("id", GetType(Integer)))
tmp_Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("name", GetType(String)))
tmp_Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Snippet", GetType(String)))
tmp_Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("description", GetType(String)))
tmp_Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("lat", GetType(Double)))
tmp_Table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("lng", GetType(Double)))

'****Some code between here left out***

Dim result() As DataRow = tmp_Table.Select("id, name, Snippet, description, lat, lng, " & _
                                           "(3959 * acos(cos(radians(" & EscapeLikeValue(center_lat) & ")) " & _
                                              "* cos(radians(lat)) " & _
                                              "* cos(radians(lng) " & _
                                              "- radians(" & EscapeLikeValue(center_lng) & ")) " & _
                                              "+ sin(radians(" & EscapeLikeValue(center_lat) & ")) " & _
                                              "* sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance " & _
                                           "FROM tmp_Table " & _
                                           "HAVING distance < " & EscapeLikeValue(radius) & " " & _
                                           "ORDER BY distance")

Private Function EscapeLikeValue(value As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(value.Length)

    For i As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
        Dim c As Char = value(i)

        Select Case c
            Case "]"c, "["c, "%"c, "*"c
                sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append("]")
                Exit Select
            Case "'"c
                sb.Append("''")
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                sb.Append(c)
                Exit Select
        End Select
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

What am I missing in order to cause that error?

Comment: You have misunderstood `DataTable.Select`. The first parameter is the filter. I guess you want to fill the table. Then you don't need to add the columns manually but use a `DataAdapter` with your select-sql and then `dataAdapter.Fill(tmp_Table)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have updated the question itself now since you gave me that advice. I am now getting a new error that i reflect on in the OP above.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said, you are not using the SELECT method correctly. Think if it as the WHERE clause of your SQL statement. For example:

```
SELECT * From Table Where ID = 45
```

You SELECT method would be:

```
Dim result() As DataRow = tmp_Table.Select("ID = 45")
```

Now, the important thing here is that it assumes you already have your table filled with data. This does NOT fill the table, it reads from the data already in the table.

Last thing to mention is that you cannot use GROUP BY or HAVING or anything like that. This is only the filter criteria.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent to *real MSSQL query* without needing to use a MS SQL server? I'm trying to get away from having to create a database.

Comment: Without a database, no. The closest you can do in VB in to use LINQ:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx